# how to set css and html structure in wp_nav_menu() function in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a HTML coded navigation menu which has `CSS` style and cool animation.
Now i wants to add this `CSS` and structure in `Word Press`. I have tried and also used in `wp_nav_menu()` .But result is so far. How could i use this CSS in Word Press. 
CSS also included and working fine if i am using statically navigation `HTML`.

```
$defaults = array(
                    'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                    'menu'            => '',
                    'container'       => 'div',
                    'container_class' => '',
                    'container_id'    => '',
                    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
                    'menu_id'         => '',
                    'echo'            => true,
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                    'before'          => '',
                    'after'           => '',
                    'link_before'     => '',
                    'link_after'      => '',
                    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                    'depth'           => 0,
                    'walker'          => ''
                );

                wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

**Wants to add this css in Wordpress navigation menu**

```
 <ul class="menu">
                            <li class="current-menu-parent"><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Lorem ipsum vivams vitae sodales">Home</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">                        
                                    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="home.html">Background Color</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="home2.html">Background Color With Fullwidth Slider</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="home3.html">Clean Style</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="home4.html">Clean Style With Fullwidth Slider</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="home5.html">Background Image</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Egestas cras eres mauri pellentesque">Pages</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="full-width.html">Full Width</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="404.html">404 Page</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a></li>
                                </ul>                        
                            </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You just use the defaults for all classes. Have a look at the [docu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to see, which of your classes you have to assign to which option. Btw what is the desired output anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not so dificult to do that. You need to declare the class of the menu in array.
here is an exemple:

```
 <?php $defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => 'TopMenu', 
    'container'       => 'ul', 
    'container_class' => 'topmenu-{topmenu slug}-container', 
    'container_id'    => 'topmenu',
    'menu_class'      => 'topmenu', 
    'menu_id'         => 'topmenu-{topmenu slug}[-{increment}]',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

In this "topmenu" is the css class. I believe that from here you will be able to customize your menu.

Hope it help's you!
If you need  a css sample, just let me know!

Comment: ok.. thankx for your kind ans.. i tries i need to do more exercise on it. thanx